# A question about the chain rule $d(g\circ f)x = dg_{f(x)} \circ df_x$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

Assume $f,g$ are smooth maps with derivative maps $df_x : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m $ and $dg_{f(x)} : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^\ell$, then chain rule say $d(g\circ f)x = dg_f(x) \circ df_x$. On the RHS of this, is it not saying $dg_{f(x)}(df_x(h))$ for some vector $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$? But this doesn't make sense since $df_x(h)$ is a scalar.

Comment: Why would $df_x(h)$ be a scalar? You wrote correctly that $df_x:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule is
$$ d(g\circ f)_x[h] = dg_{f(x)}[df_x[h]]$$
where square brackets indicate application of a linear map. You did not subscript correctly and that is quite crucial when you want to type these things out; I'm not sure what you do or don't understand.

In any case, $df_x:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ so $df_x[h]\in \mathbb R^m$ is not a scalar.

Comment: I don't know why I asked this question...